# How can I use copy constructor and static fields in my class?

Tags: java, object, static, field, copy-constructor

I have a question how can I create static fields to count the number of objects of a given class
in memory with the finalize method
(protected void finalize () throws Throwable)?
Second question, do I make copy constructors well in this class, for example, if not how should I do it?

```
public Rectangle(Rectangle point){
width = point.width
height = point.height

}
```

---

```
public class Point {
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;
        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    
        public Point(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    
    }
    class Rectangle {
        public int width = 0;
        public int height = 0;
        Point origin;
        // four constructors
        public Rectangle() {
            origin = new Point(0, 0);
        }
        public Rectangle(Point p) {
            origin = p;
        }
        public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
            this(new Point(0, 0), w, h);
        }
        public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
            origin = p;
            width = w;
            height = h;
        }
        public void move(int x, int y) {
            origin.x = x;
            origin.y = y;
        }
        public int area() {
    
            return width * height;
        }
    }

    public class exa_1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(5,10);
            myRect.width = 40;
            myRect.height = 50;
            System.out.println("Area: " + myRect.area());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for your reference:

1.) For count the object in the memory

- You can create a static class variable. Then, add the count in the constructor and reduce the counter in the finalize function.

2.) For the copy constructor, we need a deep copy as Rectangle has a mutable object. Moreover, you also need to count the object in the
memory.

Remarks: it's not recommended to use finalize() as it's
deprecated in Java 9. Here are the reasons why not to use it:

a.) No guarantee for execution in finalize(). As JVM invokes
finalize(), you might get a case where JVM exits too early and
garbage collector doesn't get enough time to create and execute
finalizers.

b.) Finalization is complex process and often leads to performance issues, deadlocks, and hangs. That's the reason Java also chose to
deprecate it.

c.) finalize() method does not work in chaining like constructors. Child class finalize() does not call super class'
finalize().

d.) Any exception thrown by the finalize method causes the finalization of this object to be halted, but is otherwise ignored.
It will not even logged in your log files. If something goes
wrong, it becomes near to impossible to debug.

```
class Point {
    public static int count = 0;
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        count++;  //Add the object count
        System.out.println("Point constructor. object count="+ count);
    }

    public Point(int x) {
        this(x,0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        count--;  //reduce the object count
        System.out.println("Point finalize. object count="+ count);
    }

}
class Rectangle {

    public static int count = 0;
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    Point origin;
    
    public Rectangle() {
        this(new Point(0, 0));
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        this(p,0,0);
    }
    public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        this(new Point(0, 0), w, h);
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        count++;  //Add the object count
        System.out.println("Rectangle constructor. object count="+ count);
    }

    //Copy constructor
    public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {

        this(new Point(rectangle.getPoint().x, rectangle.getPoint().y), rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
    }

    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }
    public int area() {

        return width * height;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
    
        return origin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        count--;  //reduce the object count
        System.out.println("Rectangle finalize. object count="+ count);
    }
}

public class exa_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(5,10);
        myRect.width = 40;
        myRect.height = 50;
        System.out.println("Area: " + myRect.area());

        Rectangle myRect2 = new Rectangle(5,10);
        myRect2.width = 60;
        myRect2.height = 70;
        System.out.println("Area: " + myRect2.area());

        Rectangle myRect3 = new Rectangle(myReact2);
        System.out.println("Area: " + myRect3.area());

        myReact = null;  //Set to null so that the object will be removed during gc
        System.gc(); //to clear the memory
    }
}
```